# How to remove/hide the name of activity from the action bar of my app. I am using Android Studio

Tags: android

Please suggest ways to remove/hide the name of activity from action bar of my app. If there is a tutorial or a guide available on how to do it, that would be great. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you need to change the theme of your application.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit it from the code then

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Edited Title");
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Edited Title");
```

this might help you https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this code before setting the content view in the activity oncreate method.

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Answer (score 0):

Just set "android:theme" attribute to "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" on your  element in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```