# android user interface developing

Tags: android

I have created a application using android studio. top of the activity application name shown. And I want to remove it.
How to remove the android application name from the bar which is in the top of the activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/hide the name of activity from the action bar of my app. I am using Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183943/how-to-remove-hide-the-name-of-activity-from-the-action-bar-of-my-app-i-am-usin)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove the title text from the Android ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655874/how-do-you-remove-the-title-text-from-the-android-actionbar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as far as I know there are few options in order to do so:

first one:  click on res-->values-->styles.xml

inside youll have few styles, in your `AppTheme` style, change it to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

second one:   (in your java class in your onCreate method):

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);    //or true if you want to see it
```

there might be more ways to do it, this are the 2 I know of.

**Note:**

in the second solution you might still get an action bar but without a title, so I highly recommend the first option for you.

**P.S:**

I saw [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183943/how-to-remove-hide-the-name-of-activity-from-the-action-bar-of-my-app-i-am-usin) post, which might help too but Im not familiar with that solution yet.